# Offline layout dependencies in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, dependencies

I'm new to Android Studio and after installing the program, I noticed that "Hello World" in the design layout only appears when when my computer is online, I guess it's because of the the dependencies in the activity_main.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The design layout loads only when my computer is online, and when it's offline, the design layout is blank, I see a bunch of class errors and project errors when it's offline such as:

Class referenced in the layout file, `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout`, was not found in the project or the libraries

Cannot resolve class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Please how do I download the dependencies offline and rewrite the http dependencies in the activity_main.xml file, so I can code when I'm offline.
Thanks

Comment: Add dependency `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4' `  for `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: please what steps do I take to add this dependency implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Bewlow Dependency in your `build.gradle` File in the `dependencies` block

```
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
```

- Like Below

[image]

- And Use it in `XML`

[image]

Comment: The implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4' already exists in my build.gradle file, can you edit the xml in my post, so I can see how you did it. When I hover on androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout, I see this message: Class referenced in the layout file, androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout, was not found in the project or the libraries

Comment: what is the error shown in logcat ?

Comment: Logcat page is blank, this is the message shown in Layout and Qualifiers panel: The following classes could not be found:
- androidx.versionedparcelable.R
- androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout (    Add constraint-layout library dependency to the project, Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project.  Tip: Try to refresh the layout.

Comment: You can restart your android studio and `invalidate chaches` option available in top menu in `File`